# What's the base class of a Razor View in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to have all my views inherit from a custom class so that I can add certain behaviour and values to all pages, but I'm having some issues. I tried subclassing System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage but I'm forced to implement an Execute procedure that I don't know what it should do. Also, if I try to access the Context variable, I get a null reference (really weird). This leads me to think that I may have the wrong base class....

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you add behaviors to all of your classes through extension methods, or do you need them to be instance methods?

Comment: Mainly I need to add some variables that can be referenced from within the views. I know I could achieve this using extension methods, but there should be a way of having custom viewpage classes as with the aspx view engine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Diego, `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` is the right base type (and you should have another class inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>` if you want strongly-typed views). You should mark your own class as `abstract` so that you are not forced to implement the Execute method.

**Update:** To configure all your views to use your custom base class, look into the `~\Views\Web.config` file. Inside of it there's a Razor-specific section where you can use the `pageBaseType` attribute to configure your custom type.

As far as the Context property is concerned, it should be fully initialized once the view is executing. However, it might not be available if you try to access it too early (for example, from your classes constructor). When are you trying to access it?

---

The Execute method is something that is provided by the Razor compiler when your view is compiled. For example, given the following view file

```
Hello @Name!
```

The Razor compiler will behind the scenes generate the following class (this is a simplification, so the details might be off, but it should convey the point)

```
public class _Some_Generated_Class_Name_ : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage {
  public void Execute() {
    Write("Hello ");
    Write(Name);
    Write("!");
  }
}
```

Then the framework calls the Execute method on your view class and your view gets executed.

Comment: In my Class's constructor :) That must be it then.

Comment: Just as an addendum to the question, what is the Execute procedure supposed to do? Is it okay if I just override it with a blank procedure?

Comment: @Diego I've edited my answer to illustrate how the compiler generates an implementation for Execute.

Comment: Is there any way of specifying the base class for all views in a directory? I'd like to have normal views inherit from my particular System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage subclass and views that specify a model to inherit from my particular System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel> subclass.

Comment: @Diego i've added an update describing where to configure your base class.

Comment: I am using .NET 6, and this is not working in my solution.  If I add Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc Nuget package, it complains that targets .NET Framework 4.8 and not 6.0.  I can't find the equivalent WebViewPage base class in .NET 6.  Do you have any ideas?