# Change the base class of a razor view in the view code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Note that this is not a duplicated question. I know we can specify a base view type in the razor section of views/web.config. But I want my view1,view2 inherit from baseviewA, and the view3,view4 inherit from baseviewB. In razor how can I do this like that in ASPX engine:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Test.Myproject.Web.Mvc.ViewBase" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Test.Myproject.Web.Mvc.PartialViewBase" %>
```

**EDIT** I don't care about models. In my question baseviewA and baseviewB are totally different classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963834/whats-the-base-class-of-a-razor-view-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: @CodeJammr: That changes all the base class of the view. I want a few different base classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the [base class in Razor](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/01/09/razor-tip-2-inheritance-amp-configuration.aspx) with the `@inherits` keyword, your base classes just need to derive from  `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.

So your sample:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Test.Myproject.Web.Mvc.ViewBase" %>`

Will be

`@inherits Test.Myproject.Web.Mvc.ViewBase`

Where

```
public class Test.Myproject.Web.Mvc.ViewBase : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
{
}
```

Comment: Is it possibel to use `<%` syntax in razor instead of `@`?

Comment: @ZainShaikh no the `<%` is not supported in razor only in aspx pages. What is your problem with the usage the `@` symbol?

Comment: May be I shall post a separate question for this, but still lets continue. I have a template file which I use with client side javascript (`underscore`) library to build user-interface. I want to render same template file from server side using `razor` engine or some other better than razor.

Answer (score 2):

Inherits specifies the model type going to be used in the view. Same this can be done in Razor.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Test.Myproject.Web.Mvc.ViewBase<Test.Models.MyModel>" %
```

is equivalent to following in Razor

```
@model Test.Models.MyModel
```

this is same in both views and partial views,So

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Test.Myproject.Web.Mvc.PartialViewBase<Test.Models.MyModelB>" %>
```

is equivalent to

```
@model Test.Models.MyModelB
```

Comment: There is no model business. I just want to change the base class of the view.

Comment: OK, then the only way would be to keep your views in different folders and have a web.config in each folder you want to override.

Comment: Are you sure we can have a few web.config files in each view folder that will `override` the config in the base `view/` folder?